# Mapbox, create area, label that area, then search for the label

Tags: search, label, mapbox, area

Total newbi here. I have played with studio for a few h but can not get over the next hurdle.

I would like to draw wine growing areas on the map.
Managed to draw areas. Tick.

I would like to give these areas a unique name.
Managed to create labels.
But I don't understand how the text is associated with the area.

I then want to search for this label, so that the map zooms in on that area.
Just like when I search for "Coburg, Victoria, Australia".

I have managed to publish my maps including the areas in my WordPress website.
So my access token and my style does the right thing.

Need some hints how to get the labelling and searching happening.

Thank you for any help.

Regards
Romano

Answer (score 0):

and welcome to using Mapbox.

> I would like to give these areas a unique name. Managed to create labels. But I don't understand how the text is associated with the area.

Have you tried creating a `Symbol` layer, and setting the `Text field` to the appropriate field in your data source?

> I then want to search for this label, so that the map zooms in on that area. Just like when I search for "Coburg, Victoria, Australia".

This goes beyond using Studio, and into building web maps with mapbox-gl-js. One starting point would be to use the Finder Impact Tool.

This might involve processing the data twice -- once for your base map, and another time in a spreadsheet to make available to the Finder template. It's possible to just do once, but would involve some modifying the Finder template.

https://labs.mapbox.com/education/impact-tools/finder-with-filters/